# Grant Select not throwing error, but not granting select permission either

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I ran a very simple GRANT SELECT statement. I didn't get any error message, but it didn't grant select permissions either:

```
GRANT SELECT ON schema_name.table_name to database_username
```

When I try to query the table with that user, I get "The SELECT permission was denied". In addition to that, I can't see the table in the Object Explorer either.

What could it be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: Is there also a DENY? DENY will always take precedence over a GRANT.

Comment: I think you have to create a role, then grant permission to the role then add the user to the role...

Comment: Does [`fn_my_permissions`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms176097%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) help pin down the issue? Work through one step at a time: server, database, table.

Comment: Did you relog with the user to whom you gave the select privilege ?  Grant permissions don't apply to sessions already opened by the user.